# JS / GS Simple Google Sheets Script

Tags: javascript

Im trying to create a simple script that firstly checks (all cells in row 3 starting from column 3) for whether they contain a name different from the available sheets and if so create a new one. If not go to the next cell down. Preferably until the row is empty but I didnt get that far. Currently I have

```js
var row = 3; //Global Variable
function Main() { // Main Function
    Activate(); 
    GetNames(); 
}
function Activate() { // Initialize
    var get = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var import = get.getSheetByName("Import");
}
function GetNames() { // Get Names and check for existing Sheets
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var import = ss.getSheetByName("Import");
    var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
    for (i = 0; i < 1000; i++) { // Loop which I think is broken
        var names = import.getRange(row,3).getValue();  
        if (import.getSheetByName(names) == null) {
            import.insertSheet(names);
            import.activate();
        } 
       row + 1;   
    }
}
```

And here is the Data

[image]

It succeeds to add the first sheet but fails to continue in the loop I think.
As you will probably see I'm very new to this and any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably wanted to increase `row` by 1 here:

```
row + 1;
```

But you're not. `row + 1` is just an **expression** with a value (4, in your example, because row remains 3 throughout). What you would need is the **statement**

```
row = row + 1;
```

But if this is all that you're using the global variable `row` for, you don't need it at all. Just use the loop variable `i` that's already counting from 0 to 1000. You probably want something like `import.getRange(i+3,3)`.

Comment: That did the trick thank you very much. Also thank you for going into further detail with the i variable!